# Change image on link click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code which display three button images and when clicked they fade in the relevant div using jQuery...

http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/11/

**HTML**

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RxSLu4i.png"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/U8Jw3U6.png"></a>


<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');

});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".link")[0].click(); 
});
```

I also have these three alternate (pressed) button images...

```
http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png
http://i.imgur.com/syroxDR.png
http://i.imgur.com/l91OpLL.png
```

I would like the images to change to these when they are clicked, can anyone help?

Comment: What I am doing is changing classes on the attribute like following: `$("#up").removeClass("thumbs-up-on").addClass("thumbs-up-off");` and the rest is CSS, so just put id="up" for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you put all display code within CSS. And then model your HTML to work more expressively.  Meaning, if you look at the html code alone, you can tell the button is pressed because the 'Down' class has been appended to it.

**CSS:**

```
        .redButton > div
        {
            background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png');
        }
        .redButton.Down > div
        {
            background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png');
        }
        .link > div
        {
            width: 88px;
            height: 88px;
            display:inline-block;
        }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $(".link").click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();

             var mainButton = $(e.target).parent();

             $('.link').not(mainButton).removeClass('Down');  

             mainButton.toggleClass('Down');
             $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');    
             $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');        
             });
```

**HTML:**

```
 <a class="link redButton" href="#" data-rel="content1">
        <div></div>
        </a>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    </div>
```

No need to maintain an image array in JavaScript (puke). And you are properly using each each layer of the HTML stack the way it was intended.

**[jsFiddle Hot Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thcP5/)**

Comment: I understand your approach, but this doesn't work for me when there are more than one button.  I also want only one button to be pressed at one time  http://jsfiddle.net/RjJdV/2/

Comment: Thats great!  In my old original version when I clicked on a button, the previously pressed one would revert back to the unpressed state allowing only one button state to be pressed http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/5/  -  Could this be implemented with your version?

Comment: Updated again. You just need to tweak the JavaScript to make sure you apply the correct classes.

Comment: What happens if they want a third image if they press the button too many times and you want to go into a disabled/lockout state? With the pure JavaScript approach you will be banging your head saving states and insuring the correct image is selected. With this approach, you could easily pull it off by adding a third class. Which keeps code maintenance linear, and not exponential.

Comment: Perfect :)  Thanks for taking the time to go through things

Comment: I have added to the jquery slightly to automatically select the first button on load.  The content loads correctly but for some reason the button isn't depressed http://jsfiddle.net/thcP5/1/

Comment: @cgatian And what if you click on a button twice?

Comment: @HashemQolami what do you mean?

Comment: @cgatian, you're toggling the class, if always one button is supposed to be selected, it shouldn't be changed when you click on it again.

Comment: @fightstarr20 I've updated to help you through the setting initial state. I'm sure there's more you need to do. Hopefully this is enough to answer the initial question and further questions can be opened for other issues. http://jsfiddle.net/8BgjT/

Comment: @HashemQolami Does my demo not do that? See the last fiddle posted

Comment: @cgatian I don't think so, when you click on the second button multiple times the class get changed multiple times as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```javascript
var imgArray = [
    'http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/syroxDR.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/l91OpLL.png'
];

$(".link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Change the image source.
      $(this).find('img').prop('src', imgArray[$(this).index()]);

      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/ttj9J/13/)**

**Update #2:**

If you need to rollback other images when you click on one, you need to store default image source at the beginning:

```
var imgArray = [
    'http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/syroxDR.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/l91OpLL.png'
], defaultImg = [];

$('.link').find('img').each(function(){
    defaultImg.push($(this).prop('src'));
});

$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(".link").find('img').each(function(i) {
        $(this).prop('src', defaultImg[i]);
    });

    $(this).find('img').prop('src', imgArray[$(this).index()]);

    $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/ttj9J/17/)**

### Update #3:

If using `imgArray` to store new `src` attributes makes the code *complicated*, you can store the `src` into `data-*` attributes, like: `data-newsrc="path/to/new/src"`, then you an get access to it simply by `$(selector).data('newsrc');`

```
$(this).find('img').prop('src', $(this).find('img').data('newsrc'));
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #3](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/ttj9J/20/)**

Comment: This kind of works, although it does not change the image back when another button is clicked.  Is there a way to have it so that only one button can be active?

Comment: Again, this kind of works but now it turns all of the buttons a different colour.  Surely an imgArray is a really long winded and over complicated approach to this?

Comment: @fightstarr20 Added fiddle for new solution.

Answer (score 0):

**http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/19/**

JS

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');

      //retrieve src for the new img
      var new_img_src = $(this).data('newimg');
      var current_img = jQuery("img", this);

      //swap data-newimg src with current src
      $(this).data('newimg', current_img.attr("src"));    
      current_img.attr("src",new_img_src);

      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');     
});
```

Html

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1" data-newimg="http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png">
</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2" data-newimg="http://i.imgur.com/syroxDR.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RxSLu4i.png">
</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3" data-newimg="http://i.imgur.com/l91OpLL.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U8Jw3U6.png">
</a>


<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
</div>
```